# Can I Rebuild indexes in a DB except for one table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, maintenance

I have a table in my database that is constantly monitored by an application server for changes. Unfortunately rebuilding the indexes connected with this table breaks the app server's connection. This causes print jobs and various other processes to fail silently on the application server.

I have created a small monitoring SQL job that lets me know when this happens, but I would prefer to prevent it from happening in the first place.

I need to rebuild indexes weekly for performance reasons, but I would be fine with skipping the indexes associated with that table.

How can I rebuild indexes for the rest of the database without touching that table?

Edit: I am currently using an SSIS job (the canned maintenance plan) to rebuild all indexes for all tables in the DB. After that it updates stats and checks integrity.

Comment: Well, how are you rebuilding the indexes now? Are you really just running a loop and saying "rebuild all indexes on all tables"?

Comment: I have been relying on an SSIS job that rebuilds all indexes for all tables in a specific database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement a better solution, such as Michelle Ufford's - it will perform much more intelligent decisions on which indexes to defrag, rebuild or leave alone, and it is very easy to have exclusions:

http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1/

Comment: That is a seriously powerful script. I've dropped it into my test environment and will begin playing with it right away. My only question (probably a dumb one), to exclude a table I would just add it to the dba_indexDefragExclusion table? I don't see anything in the code stating a best practice for doing that (I'm assuming just an insert statement).

Comment: Yes I think it is just going to be a simple insert statement.

Comment: In conclusion, Michelle Ufford's script has an exclusion table. My pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/qyV8DvVZ) shows you how to retrieve the data you need to insert exclusion rows into Michelle's exclusion table. Then you simply run her sproc to reindex your database(s) intelligently and with any specified exclusions. It's beautiful.

Comment: And I waited until now to mention that my company's product, SQL Sentry Performance Advisor, includes a facility to do this and more: http://sqlsentry.net/fragmentation-manager/sql-server-index-analysis-and-defrag.asp but it's not free like Michelle's. :-)